# php version showing different in application/browser

Tags: php, linux, apache, vagrant

I have installed ubuntu/trusty64 using vagrant on my windows pc. I have installed all the required package for php development environment.

Now problem is while I check php version on browser it's showing different from terminal.

From application browser showing :

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
```

Terminal showing:

```
PHP 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
```

Why different version showing on my application?

Please let me know how can I sync up application with php 5.6.27 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then the difference between your terminal and the application is the PHP source that they are getting the information from. If you had installed PHP apart from your application, that's why is showing different versions.

To change this (for example that you want to have only the PHP that your terminal is displaying:`PHP 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)`, then change the pointer from your application to point to the directory where PHP 5.6 is installed (For Ubuntu: `/usr/share/php5`).

Answer (score 4):

//php 7.0 to php 7.2 switcher

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.2 
sudo systemctl restart apache2

sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/php7.2 /etc/alternatives/php
```